# How to print the map like a template?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Here is my code:

To understand the code I have to explain a little. First I am getting student and course data from user in different classes. Then in Schedule class I am trying to create a schedule for student. When user enter a valid student and course name I am inserting these datas to another map.

```
map< string,map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> > >  courseScList;
map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> > matchMap;
```

matchMap map has these datas from another class:

```
course name,course hours,course day,available hours in this day
```

These 2 are mine maps and I am using these maps in this code:

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule() {
    string c,s;
    int courseNum;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map< string,map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> > >::iterator last;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> >::iterator location;
    map<pair<string,int>,pair<string ,Array> >::iterator match;
    dummy1:
    cout<<"Enter the student name"<<endl;
    cin >> s;
    wrongCourse:
    cout<<"Enter the course names you want"<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
    studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(),getStudentList().end(),s);
    location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
    if(studentLoc != getStudentList().end() || location != getMatchMap().end())
    {
        getCourseScList().insert(make_pair(s,getMatchMap()));
    }
    else
        {
        cout<<"The course or student you wrote isn't available.Please enter existed courses!"<<endl;
        goto wrongCourse;
        }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    char dummy;
    cout<<"\nDo tou want to create a new schedule?Press y or n."<<endl;
    cin>>dummy;
    if(dummy == 'Y' || dummy == 'y')
        goto dummy1;
    else
    {
        location = last->second.begin();
        for(last = getCourseScList().begin();last!=getCourseScList().end();++last)
        {
                cout<<last->first<<"\t"<<(location->first).first<<"\t"<<(location->second).first<<"\t";
                for (const int element : location->second.second)
                    std::cout << element << " ";
                cout<<endl;
            ++location;
        }

    }
```

I am trying to get student and course name from user and if student name and course name in the map I am inserting this to another map. However when I try to print these student,course,day and day hours data I can't see these in same line. I think the wrong code is this:

```
 else
            {
            cout<<"The course or student you wrote isn't available.Please enter existed courses!"<<endl;
            goto wrongCourse;
            }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        char dummy;
        cout<<"\nDo tou want to create a new schedule?Press y or n."<<endl;
        cin>>dummy;
        if(dummy == 'Y' || dummy == 'y')
            goto dummy1;
        else
        {
            location = last->second.begin();
            for(last = getCourseScList().begin();last!=getCourseScList().end();++last)
            {
                    cout<<last->first<<"\t"<<(location->first).first<<"\t"<<(location->second).first<<"\t";
                    for (const int element : location->second.second)
                        std::cout << element << " ";
                    cout<<endl;
                ++location;
            }

        }
```

With this print loop i can't see the template like this;

```
Studentname1  -- > Coursename1 ----> Courseday1 -->Coursehours1
Studentname1  -- > Coursename2 ----> Courseday2 -->Coursehours1
Studentname2  -- > Coursename1 ----> Courseday1 -->Coursehours1
Studentname3  -- > Coursename2 ----> Courseday2 -->Coursehours
```

This is just an example what I want to do. How can I organize the code for it?

Comment: As already state, try to create **minimal** complete verifiable example (MCVE). if your issue is just to display `std::map` just provide hardcoded map and try to display it.

Comment: The problem is when i insert the datas to courseScList map, I can't see the matchMap map's datas. I dont know how can I minimalize my question :(

Comment: Don't use `goto`. It's not the 1950s any more.

Comment: Your questions is only to implement `void print(const map< string,map<pair<string,int>,pair<string,Array> > >&)`, right?

Comment: Partially,yeah. How can I print the last map like my template as I mentioned in question

Comment: Am I inserting the string s and matchMap map truely at 20.line

Comment: @molbdnilo I am a beginner for c++ programming, what I use instead of goto?

Comment: So what is the output you see now? Have you tried stepping through in the debugger?

Comment: @jignatius I cant see anything for now. However as i understand the for loop I create for printing the data is not working correctly

Comment: I changed the code a little bit. `for(last = getCourseScList().begin();last!=getCourseScList().end();++last)
        {
                location = last->second.begin();
                cout<<last->first<<"\t"<<(location->first).first<<"\t"<<(location->second).first<<"\t";
                for (const int element : location->second.second)
                    std::cout << element << " ";
                cout<<endl;
        }` And now i can just see the map's first line.

Comment: You probably should have dedicated structure instead of those `std::pair` for readability.

Comment: What can I use for it? @Jarod42

Comment: @sonelektrikci A dedicated structure or class, that has meaningfull named members instead of just first and second.